# When using a slack incoming_webhook and a video_url pointing to my app, i get "invalid_blocks"

Tags: slack-api

I made a slack app that has an incoming webhook that basically posts to a slack channel with an image or video.  Images work fine, however when trying to use a video block it fails.  I've narrowed it down to the "video_url" property that, for now, points directly to an s3 link to the video file.  If i change that to a youtube link (for example) it works fine.

In the block kit tool, i get an error stating "video validation failed, bot scope missing", however my bot scope has all the required scopes.  I also added these scopes to the User Token Scopes as well.  I also added the s3 domain to my app unfurl domains.

Block kit still gives me the error and any time i make a request to the incoming webhook, all i get is a bad request with "invalid_blocks"

I feel like i'm just missing some small piece of the puzzle

Answer (score 1):

i contacted slack and got it sorted, kinda.  They said there was an issue using video blocks with a webhook, but the [postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) api call worked fine